# Which layout should I be using?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have created a form with 5 buttons using a GridBagLayout to get this form:
[image: This is the form I have created]

What I want is for The buttons to be bigger and more evenly spaced like this:[image: Desired Form]

Here is my code:

```
package com.GUI;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.seaglasslookandfeel.*;


public class JFramePlus extends JFrame{
    public JFramePlus(){
        super("OmegaBrain");
        setSize(1000,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
        setResizable(false);

    }

}
```

This is the superclass of the class in question.

```
package com.GUI;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Stack;



class GamePlay extends JFramePlus implements ActionListener{

    //Create Stack
    Stack sequence = new Stack();

    //Declare Variables
    String greekSequence;
    int stackCount;
    int timeLeft;
    static int optionNo;

    //Create Constraints
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    //Defining new objects
    JLabel timeDisplay, sequenceViewer;
    JButton mainMenu, input1, input2, input3, input4, input5;
    JPanel timerPane, centerPane, exitPane;
    Timer t;


    GamePlay(){


        //Create Labels
        timeDisplay = new JLabel();
        sequenceViewer = new JLabel();

        //Create Panels
        timerPane = new JPanel();
        centerPane = new JPanel();     
        exitPane = new JPanel();

        //Change layout of centerPane
        centerPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        //Creates JButtons
        mainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");

        input1 = new JButton("Ξ");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
        centerPane.add(input1, c);    

        input2 = new JButton("Ω");
            c.gridx = 2;
            c.gridy = 1;
        centerPane.add(input2, c);

        input3 = new JButton("Ψ");
            c.gridx = 4;
            c.gridy = 1;
        centerPane.add(input3, c);

        input4 = new JButton("Φ");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 2;
        centerPane.add(input4, c);

        input5 = new JButton("Γ");
            c.gridx = 3;
            c.gridy = 2;
        centerPane.add(input5, c);

        //Create Timer
        t = new Timer(1000, this);


        //Changes the size of the font
        timeDisplay.setFont(timeDisplay.getFont().deriveFont(64.0f));

        //Generate Sequence
        sequenceGenerator();


        //Add components to panels
        timerPane.add(timeDisplay);

        centerPane.add(sequenceViewer, c);

        exitPane.add(mainMenu);



        //add panels to frame
        add(timerPane, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(exitPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        //Change colors to fit theme
        timeDisplay.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        sequenceViewer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        timerPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        centerPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        exitPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        //Add ActionListeners to buttons
        mainMenu.addActionListener(this);
        input1.addActionListener(this);
        input2.addActionListener(this);
        input3.addActionListener(this);
        input4.addActionListener(this);
        input5.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void sequenceGenerator(){
        sequence.push(1 + (int)(Math.random() * optionNo));
        stackCount++;

        greekSequence = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < stackCount; i++){
            if (sequence.get(i) == 1){
                greekSequence = greekSequence + 'Ξ';
            }
        }
        sequenceViewer.setText(greekSequence);
    }




    void startTimer() {
        t.start();

    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Object source = evt.getSource();
        if(source == t){
            timeDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(timeLeft));
            timeLeft--;

            if(timeLeft == -1){
                t.stop();
            }
        }

        else if(source == mainMenu){
            int yesNo = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(  
                null,
                "Are you sure you want to exit? Your current score will be saved as it is." ,
                "Exit Game?",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if(yesNo == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                dispose();
                mainMenu menu = new mainMenu();
            }

            else{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loaded question. I'll start by saying `GridBagLayout` is just fine for what you're trying to achieve. I think you should invest some time looking into: [How to Use `GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

You should also look into "Insets" for spacing options, and utilizing `gridwidth`, `gridheight`, and maybe even `ipadx` and `ipady` when dealing with `GridBagConstraints`.

Comment: I agree with using GBL. Some tips for 'bigger buttons' would be to increase the font size used, or to call [`AbstractButton.setMargin(Instets)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin-java.awt.Insets-).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a BoxLayout. ([How to use `BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) ).

You would be able to position your components as desired and if you want to add space between components, you can add an empty border to your components or put invisible components between them.

You can see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335997/how-can-i-add-a-space-in-between-two-buttons-in-a-boxlayout) for more information.